# Pass a variable to php with $

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a variable to php inside the if statement. The problem is that the variable to be passed to, is another variable starting with $ so I get an error that says `A non-numeric value encountered` and `Illegal string offset`. So is there a way to achieve this?

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $request = "$"+"_POST";

} else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
   
    $request = "$"+"_GET";
}

    $val = htmlspecialchars_decode($request["value01"], ENT_QUOTES);

?>
```

Comment: String concatenation is via `.` in PHP, not `+`.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the `$_REQUEST` superglobal can read from both POST and GET variables, making this code pretty much redundant - `$request["value01"]` could be replaced with `$_REQUEST["value01"]` and then the whole `if` block would be unnecessary. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you are making this so hard for yourself...

Get rid of the string concatenation and just refer to the global directly.

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $request = $_POST;

} else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
   
    $request = $_GET;
}

    $val = htmlspecialchars_decode($request["value01"], ENT_QUOTES);

?>
```

Comment: This is correct, assuming that's what OP _actually_ wanted to do, it's not all that clear 

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the `$_REQUEST` superglobal can read from both POST and GET variables, making this code pretty much redundant - `$request["value01"]` could be replaced with `$_REQUEST["value01"]` and then the whole `if` block would be unnecessary. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Ah thanks i am so dumb that i was doing all complicated stuff

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is the use of `$$`.

Look at this, might be helpful:

```php
$variable1 = "Anything ...";

$variable2 = "variable1";
echo $$variable2; // Anything ...
```

So your code will be like this:

```php
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $request = "_POST";

} else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
   
    $request = "_GET";
}

$val = htmlspecialchars_decode($$request["value01"], ENT_QUOTES);

?>
```

If you wanted to know the syntax that's OK; but if you want to implement the exact code as you mentioned, that's a bit useless.

There is a global in php called `$_REQUEST` which stores both `$_POST` and `$_GET` values. Look at this:

```php
// Method is GET
echo $_REQUEST['test']; // test values printed
echo $_GET['test']; // test values printed
echo $_POST['test']; // ERROR

// Method is POST
echo $_REQUEST['test']; // test values printed
echo $_GET['test']; // ERROR
echo $_POST['test']; // test values printed
```